# Ubuntu 18.04 no kernel

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, kernel

everybody. I had nvidia driver with 396 and after some days I received kernel update 4.15 and I upgraded kernel to 4.15. Then I could not launch games. It said some nvidia errors in my kernel version 4.15. I removed kernel 4.15 with synaptics and I then booted with 4.13 kernel. BUt in terminal when I wrote "sudo apt autoremove" terminal offered me to remove my kernel 4.13. And I pressed "y" and kernel uninstalled and then rebooted. No kernels now in GRUB menu.
I need help to install back my old kernel with nvidia driver 396.

Comment: I solved the kernel problem, now I have 4.15. How can I make 4.13 as a default kernel in my Ubuntu 18.04 x64?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)